# Mysql search for one way flight on specific date

Tags: java, html, mysql, tomcat9

```
CREATE TABLE `FlightOperatedby` (
  `2-let ID` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `flight #` int DEFAULT 0,
  `departing airport` char(3),
  `arriving airport` char(3),
  `a. time` time,
  `d. time` time,
`duration` varchar(100),
  `number of stops` int,
    `isinternational` boolean,
  `isdomestic` boolean,
  `fare_first` double,
`fare_business` double,
`fare_economy` double,
  PRIMARY KEY (`2-let ID`,`flight #`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`departing airport`) REFERENCES Airport(`3-let ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY (`arriving airport`) REFERENCES Airport(`3-let ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) 
CREATE TABLE `AircraftFlightDates` (
    `2-let ID` char(2),
    `aircraft #` int,
    `operating day` varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (`2-let ID`, `aircraft #`, `operating day`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`2-let ID`, `aircraft #`) REFERENCES Aircraft(`2-let ID`, `aircraft #`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

I am creating a flight reservation system where a customer logs in and searches for a one-way flight on a specific date. Right now, for the sql command, I have

```
String searchOneWay = 
"SELECT flight #, a. time, d. time, departing airport, arriving airport, 2-let id" 
+ "FROM FlightOperatedby join AircraftFlightDates using(flight #, 2-let id)" 
+ "WHERE ";
```

If the customer searches for a flight on 11/23/2021, I have to match the flights that operate on that day (Tuesday) to the flights that the customer wants, but I can't figure out a way to connect the operating days of the aircrafts to actual real life dates so that the customer can actually select a date.

Comment: Find out which day of the week 11/23/2021 is.

Comment: Yes, I can’t figure out a way to program that in sql given the user’s input.